# OpenGL: Render image 3D point cloud

Tags: image, opengl, 3d, 2d, point

I have a point cloud of (x,y,z) points with colour and being rendered in openGL window using glDrawArray(). Now I have a camera pose and I'd like to render the points from this camera pose which is basically projecting all the 3D points in this camera frame-of-reference given camera internal parameters e.g. focal length etc and [R|t].

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to render this image rather than writing a code snippet that loops though all the points and projects them in the image plane and gives me the colour. Does OpenGL have some function of that sort inbuilt that does the job for this? Another thing I'd like to know is if there is also a function that tells which points are visible in the frame rather than looping through all the N 3D points. Is there anything like that to do it efficiently?

Comment: For the first part of your question: You can set up the OpenGl projection and modelview matrices (or the matrices used in your vertex shader) to match your camera pose and *intrinsic* camera parameters (at least if you have a pinhole camera model).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you assign your points to something like a [BSP tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) you are going to have to loop over them all to see if they're visible or not.

However, by using some sort of spatial hierarchy you can quickly decide which points **aren't** visible. For example, if you divide your space into a 10 x 10 x 10 grid of cells and assign the points to one of the cells you can then check the bounding box of each cell to determine whether that cell is visible or not. So if you have 100,000 points you'll have 1,000 cells and (assuming your points are evenly distributed) you will be checking 6 points (the corners of the box) instead of 100 for each cell.

You can quickly determine which cells are totally visible or totally invisible and then you only have to check the contents of those cells that are partially visible.

By extending the hierarchy so your top level cells contain more smaller cells rather than the points you can cope with larger point clouds.

You could also vary the size of the cells so that they all contain the same number of points.

Comment: Thanks Chris! This is helpful to know.